# PHP mySQLi prepare fails with duplicate column '?'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to prepare a statement with mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY INTO `user` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Department`, `Email`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?,?,?,?) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `Email` FROM `user` WHERE `Email` = ? ) LIMIT 1;");
if (!$stmt) {
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error);
    die;
}

$statementReturnCode = $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $ssoFirstName, $ssoLastName, $ssoDepartment, $ssoEmail, $ssoEmail);
if (!$statementReturnCode) {
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

When this is run I receive the following error:

```
errno: 1060, error: Duplicate column name '?'
```

I've been able to bind in this fashion in the past, but I've never tried to bind the same column twice in a different location in the query (Email).

How can I use the same value for Email in two different locations, or is this a different issue?

To clarify what is being done with this query:

This query will be run frequently. If the user exists already in the user table, no insert should be attempted. If the user does not exist, the user should be added to the user table.

The user table has a UserID field that auto-increments. If an insert is attempted the user will not be added due to a unique constraint, but the AUTO-INCREMENT will add 1 even though the insert did not occur. This WHERE NOT EXISTS query is an attempt to mitigate this issue.

Example use:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (
    `user`.`FirstName`, 
    `user`.`LastName`, 
    `user`.`Department`, 
    `user`.`Email`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'John', 'Doe', 'Marketing', 'John.Doe@mycorp.com') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT `user`.`Email` 
    FROM `user` 
    WHERE `user`.`Email` = 'John.Doe@mycorp.com'
) LIMIT 1;
```

I have tested this query and it works as I had expected. The issue I'm having is with properly changing this query into a prepared statement with php.

Comment: Column names aren't string literals, you don't bind column names

Comment: The SELECT statement in the subquery is not binding column names, just telling mySQL what to output. Example valid query (SELECT 'Hello Stack Exchange';)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cannot be done. Prepared statements using PHP's mysqli extension cannot be used for several things including:

- Table names
- Columns in select lists

I was attempting to use a dynamic item in a select list which cannot be done.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Where_prepared_statements_do_not_work

Comment: who said you that you cannot bind LIMIT qualifiers? and you aren't selecting coluns, but strings.

Comment: The page I linked to said so, and I am selecting strings in the select list which is also not allowed (and did not work spurring this question).

Comment: Then this page tells you rubbish. Selecting strings is perfectly allowed in SQL.

Comment: You cannot select a dynamic string as a column using prepared statements like I had tried to do in the question above. If you can find a way to do this with PHP's mysqli then please provide an answer to the question. As it stands now I have found no such solution.

Comment: For a simple select you can.

Comment: Obviously, but this is not a simple select.

Comment: In your answer, two statements out of three are false. Let me advise you to concentrate on your particular issue only, leaving generalized statements aside.

Comment: After testing these on phpfiddle you are correct that limit qualifiers are allowed in mysqli's prepared statement implementation so I removed that from the list. However table names and columns in select lists still failed so they will remain in the answer. Gist: https://gist.github.com/Burke9077/d5020a972f06c9841757b28dc5149769

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116115/discussion-between-burke9077-and-your-common-sense).

Answer (score 1):

Column names aren't string literals, you don't bind column names

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(sprint("INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY INTO `user` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Department`, `Email`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `Email` FROM `user` WHERE `Email` = ? ) LIMIT 1;"), $ssoFirstName, $ssoLastName, $ssoDepartment, $ssoEmail);
if (!$stmt) {
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error);
    die;
}

$statementReturnCode = $stmt->bind_param("s", $ssoEmail);
if (!$statementReturnCode) {
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: I'm using this insert statement to avoid mySQL from autoincrementing each time a duplicate is found. If the user's email is not found in the table this query should insert a new user (with FirstName, LastName, etc...) so those columns cannot be ignored. I will update the question with an example of this.

Comment: Try with modified code.... but make sure that `$ssoFirstName`, `$ssoLastName`, `$ssoDepartment` and `$ssoEmail` are all properly escaped and sanitised first

Comment: Why would you prevent MySQL from autoincrementing? OCD problem, you're bothered with "gaps"? Doing a check yourself instead of just inserting + having a unique key on that column means you will end up with duplicates eventually since you just opened yourself to concurrency issues.

Comment: Depending on how often the query is hit, it may be an issue (thousands of times daily in this case). Doing the query this way and having a unique constraint resolves the issue. I have temporarily escaped the source since it's trustworthy enough to do that (shibboleth data), but I still want an answer as to how this could be done.